# How to setup NDK in eclipse Juno in ubuntu?

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, android-ndk

I am setting up Android NDK but its not happening as said at many sources that install a new software using the link https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ there will be a NDK plugin option but when I am doing that its not showing up.[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install the `developer tools` at the link you showed,

```
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
```

Then you need to download the ndk for your platform, manually by going to this url and clicking the correct version.

```
https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html
```

Then you can go to `Preferences/Android/NDK` and set path to where ever you put the `NDK` folder you downloaded.

So if you put the folder on the desktop just click on browse from the options I just mentioned and click on the folder, then click the open button and it will find it.

If you open the folder it will look in the next directory. Super annoying let me know if you need more help.

Comment: No problem! :) I hope that helps more people.

Answer (score 0):

Probably its the best to download and install the whole Eclipse ADT Bundle http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

The bundle has Eclipsed integrated with Android SDK as well as CDT for Android NDK. You just need to download the NDK, then in Preference-->Android-->NDK you point it to where you extract the NDK. CDT is necessary if you want syntax highlighting for your JNI development.